# Problem with laptop battery

Tags: laptop, battery

I have a very strange, for me at least ;), problem with my battery...

The original battery life was a little less than two hours. However at some point, only a few months after I had bought it, the AC adaptor stopped functioning and I used one of those multi-voltage ones for a couple of months until the place I bought it from finally replaced the original AC adaptor. I understand that all this definetely would have taken a toll on my battery.

Now, when I use it on battery, the laptop just switches off when the battery is 83-87% (after 15 mins) with no apparent reason. I have run a million of programs to test the battery, and all of them give me approximately a 25% wear of the battery and an average estimated battery life of 1h 10 mins, which I consider acceptable (I have the laptop for 14 months now).

Does anyone have any idea why it crashes after only 15 mins? Everything is ok when it's running on AC...

Answer (score 1):

Can be both memory effect in battery, or as Dynamic I suggested error on software (bios or firmware). Did you googled for this type  of battery?

Comment: Yes I did, but not with much luck... It's a Hasee s20 Lithium-Ion. What should I look for in bios or firmware? Sorry if I am too ignorant... ;)

Comment: Yes, look for bios or firmware update. Also - google laptop brand and type. Sometimes it helps. And if you could borrow some spare battery from someone, you will be able to test if this is a computer or battery failure.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check the [BatteryCare application](http://batterycare.bkspot.com/en/guide.html).
Don't know if you have already covered it...

> BatteryCare is a software created to optimize the usage and performance of the modern laptop's battery.
>   It monitors the battery's discharge cycles and helps increasing it's autonomy and improving its lifetime

---

Update:
Since its a short period to test,
have you checked what happens if you boot to the BIOS screen and wait there on battery?
You may have a battery problem.
This test should at least put you on the right side of hardware/software problem fence.
Since all OS/software is bypassed.

Comment: I installed BatteryCare. It gives 1h 28mins in the beginning, again crashed after 13 mins... :(

Answer (score 0):

Since the computer is crashing at 83-87 percent, it could be that something is wrong with the computer software and that the computer is killing it self because it improperly read the amount of battery power left.

Comment: What kind of software could do that? Any suggestions? Thanx!